# Two questions about WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Why, when defining classes that inherit from [`ClientBase<TChannel>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0), the service interface is "embedded" twice, one via composition (the generics in `<TChannel>`) and another via inheritance and not just one (like the composite one)?

On another thing, we make a successful call to a custom client proxy method which in place calls a method of the `base.channel` interface pointer, and we're having an issue where, upon next calling another client proxy function (which also redirects to another `base.channel` one), the `base.channel` property became `null` (so by the time the function is called), raising eventually a `NullReferenceException`. Why can this happen? (We create our `ClientBase` proxy with the default constructor, not providing any binding info). EDIT: The problem wasn't that the `base.channel` pointer is set to `null` after the first function call, it's that a new instance of the custom service gets created on each call. How to ensure same object is used through?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Also, WCF is kind of dead or dying whichever way you look at it, are you sure you want to develop new applications in it?

Comment: Note the first question shall not require an example. But I already found the solution to the coding question (answering in a while). And, well, I didn't really know it was downrising; my boss just designated this for a new project which wasn't even assigned to me, this was to help my mate. But thanks, I might let the boss know.

Comment: @CodeCaster Btw what's the/a better, modern alternative to WCF then for C#?

Comment: It depends on what you want. I'm all for JSON/REST for web services, gRPC for IPC and SignalR/Websockets for site-to-backend communication, security all handled on the TLS layer.

Comment: In the first question, you mean that clientbase will have two implementation methods？

Comment: On the following link there's just an official example of what I mean: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.clientbase-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#examples. Why `ISampleService` "needs" to be included twice? (again, both with generic templating composition and with direct inheritance). And I'm asking for a well-formed reason, not just a vague response.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my second question. The solution (at least in our case) was to establish the following property: `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode?view=netframework-4.8).

Nonetheless anyone is free to answer my first semantical question and I'll reward accordingly.